# Using unique_ptr Creates Error "Unable to start program" in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, unique-ptr

## The problem

In a 2D game I am creating, I have a few vector lists in the `game` class that hold pointers to game objects. These were defined like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Enemy>> enemies;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items;
```

I iterate through them using the following code:

```
for (std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Enemy>>::iterator it = enemies.begin(); it != enemies.end(); ++it) {
    (*it)->Draw(screen);

for (std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>::iterator it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it) {
    (*it)->Draw(screen);
```

At first this worked fine, however, at a certain point, the game didn't run anymore and gave me the "Unable to start program" error when trying to start debugging. I searched for solution online, but couldn't find anything that worked for me.

The reason why I put these vectors in this answer is because when the loops were removed, the game would run. I even found out that only removing the second loop (`items`) would make the game run. Then I changed the `items` array to a standard pointer vector `std::vector<Item*>` and the new loop would work. Looping through it with the following code worked like it should:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    items[i]->Draw(screen);
```

Then I changed the code back to use an `unique_ptr`, and removed the code that fill the vector. Now the game would run too, so I am afraid that I am doing something wrong here. This is how I fill the vector:

```
std::unique_ptr<Item> sword(new Item(118 * tilesize, 81 * tilesize, "Sword"));
items.push_back(std::move(sword));
```

Which is strange again, since the `enemies` vector gets filled the same way.

**Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong, and why Visual Studio is building the project, but cannot run it since there is no .exe?**

---

## Code that may be relevant

### Item class

```
class Item : public GameObject
{
public:
    Item() {}
    Item(int, int, char*);
    virtual ~Item(void) {}

    void Draw(Surface*);
}; // Item class

Item::Item(int x, int y, char *itemname) :
    GameObject(x, y) {
    tag = "Item";
    name = itemname;

    if (name == "Sword") {
        sprite = spr_item_sword;
    } else if (name == "Coconut") {

    }
}

void Item::Draw(Surface *dest) {
    GameObject::Draw(dest);
}
```

### GameObject class

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    Vec2D position;
    Sprite *sprite;
    char *tag, *name;

    GameObject(void) {}
    GameObject(int, int);
    virtual ~GameObject(void) {}

    virtual void Draw(Surface*);
}; // GameObject class
```

### Log

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Zelda, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 25-10-2013 16:04:26.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\Zelda.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  game.cpp
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(753): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(746) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<_Ty>::reserve(unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Tmpl8::TileGraph
1>          ]
1>          MY_PATH_TO_FILE\game.h(40) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Tmpl8::TileGraph
1>          ]
1>  item.cpp
1>  template.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Link:
1>  LINK : MY_PATH_TO_FILE\Debug\Zelda.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>     Creating library MY_PATH_TO_FILE\Debug\Zelda.lib and object MY_PATH_TO_FILE\Tile Cutter\Debug\Zelda.exp
1>MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>Manifest:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LinkEmbedManifest:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  Tile_Cutter.vcxproj -> MY_PATH_TO_FILE\Debug\Zelda.exe
1>FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>  Deleting file "Debug\Zelda.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>  Touching "Debug\Zelda.lastbuildstate".
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.10
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: So if there is no .exe, does that mean your project does not compile ? You should at least be able to see some info in the output pane about the stuff being compiled and the .exe file being created

Comment: It says it succeeds the build `Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped`, and there is a path saying where the `.exe` is located, but there is none. I'll post the log in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling the exact same code on a machine with Visual Studio 2012 worked, so I tried it on my own machine as well. It seems that did the trick.

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 (and changing some properties, e.g. for output directory) and compiling it, the program ran at once without any problems, even when using `unique_ptr`s again.

I hope this helps anyone in a similar situation.

### EDIT:

I found out that disabling my **Anti-virus** works as well. It didn't gave me any notice about deleting the .exe, though, but it did anyway.